# Code::Blocks debugger can't open source file

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

When I try to debug any program, I get an error "**Cannot open file: Blocks/Default/main.cpp**" full debugger logs:

```
Active debugger config: GDB/CDB debugger:Default
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: /home/alex/Documents/Code::Blocks/Default/
Adding source dir: /home/alex/Documents/Code::Blocks/Default/
Adding file: /home/alex/Documents/Code::Blocks/Default/bin/Debug/Default
Changing directory to: /home/alex/Documents/Code::Blocks/Default/.
Set variable: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:
Starting debugger: /usr/bin/gdb -nx -fullname -quiet  -args /home/alex/Documents/Code::Blocks/Default/bin/Debug/Default
done
Registered new type: wxString
Registered new type: STL String
Registered new type: STL Vector
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (Debian 7.7.1+dfsg-5) 7.7.1
Cannot open file: Blocks/Default/main.cpp
At Blocks/Default/main.cpp:5
Debugger finished with status 0
```

I'm running Debian 8.3 jessie, Code::Blocks svn build rev 10637, gdb (Debian 7.7.1+dfsg-5) 7.7.1, terminal: "gnome-terminal -t $TITLE -x" 
I'm using default Code::Blocks settings. Source file is located in project's directory, compilation and running works fine...

I also get "**warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted**" when I run the debugger, but I searched the web and it seems that this warning is normal and should be ignored...

Comment: I assume the problem is the `::` in your path. I would try to close all instances of Code::Blocks and rename the folder `Code::Blocks` to `CodeBlocks`. `PATH` variables are usually separated by colons. This would also explain why the file path is `Blocks/Default/main.cpp`.

Comment: @SimonKraemer Renaming the folder fixed the problem, thanks!